# How to click on button "Submit Quote" its id="div_5_1_1-lnk" is dynamically changing in different pages of applications

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<div id="Form_Scope1" class="Form_Scope topLevel CoachView CoachView_show" data-eventid="" data-viewid="Form_Scope1" data-config="config1" data-bindingtype="" data-binding="" data-type="com.ibm.bpm.coach.Snapshot_a30ea40f_cb24_4729_a02e_25dc8e12dcab.Form_Scope">
<div id="Action_Group2" class="Action_Group topLevel CoachView CoachView_show" data-eventid="" data-viewid="Action_Group2" data-config="config9" data-bindingtype="" data-binding="" data-type="com.ibm.bpm.coach.Snapshot_a30ea40f_cb24_4729_a02e_25dc8e12dcab.Action_Group">
<div id="div_5_1" class="ContentBox" data-view-managed="true" style="display: none;"> </div>
<div class="s-action-group clearfix sticky">
<div class="l-nodeId" style="">QTO001_N002A</div>
<div class="p-action-group">
<div id="div_5_1_1" class="Action CoachView CoachView_show" data-eventid="boundaryEvent_7" data-viewid="Action3" data-config="config15" data-bindingtype="" data-binding="" data-type="com.ibm.bpm.coach.Snapshot_a30ea40f_cb24_4729_a02e_25dc8e12dcab.Action">
<button id="div_5_1_1-lnk" class="p-primary-btn btn btn-primary" type="button" title="" data-original-title="" style="background-color: rgb(56, 168, 182);">
<i class="icon-indent-right"></i>
<span>Submit quote</span>
</button>
<a href="#action" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

How to click on button "Submit Quote" its 
1.id="div_5_1_1-lnk"  = one page of application
2.id ="div_9_1_1-lnk" = Another page of application
is dynamically changing in different pages of applications.
I have tried by xpath expression by position or relative path it is not working please let me know any other option available for this?

Comment: how about the class name of the Button tag, does it remain the same???

Answer (score 1):

The following selector would work,

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.Action button[id$='lnk']"));
```

Here '$' indicates that the id of button should end with value 'lnk'.

> - `The equals sign in attribute selectors may be prefaced by other characters which alter the meaning a bit.`
> - `Remember that classes and ID's are attributes too, and can be used with attribute selectors.`

[Refer this for more info.](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/)

Comment: purely subjective, but i'd actually use the selector `div.Action button[$='lnk']`  It selects the same thing, but is much cleaner :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[id^='div_']"));`

Comment: This will locate `line 3` and `line 7` as well.Hence **both id and class name** should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Click it using the class name

```
options=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("icon-indent-right")
for option in options:
    if(option.text=="Submit quote"):
        option.click()
```