# Selenium Webdriver & findelement

Tags: java, html, selenium

I want to find a element, xpath is like this

`"//div[@id='contentPane']/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div"`
    and then do "clickAt"

If I use

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='contentPane']/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div");
    Actions clicker = new Actions(driver);
    clicker.moveToElement(baseElement).moveByOffset(0, 0).click().perform();`

I receive Exception "`Element not found`". 
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The xpath seems to be incorrect.  If you add html, it would help someone to help you

Comment: Xpath seems to be very wrong. You can remove everything and use only the id. Should work.

Comment: in IDE its like this "clickAt //div[@id='contentPane']/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div"

Comment: I can't use inly the id, becouse it's changing after every refreshing page

Comment: Help us with the html. It will be easy for us.

Answer (score 0):

The use of such long xpaths will cause test cases to fail,a new div can be added or removed dynamically.There should be some part of the id which remains constant.

For example in `id = "someString_1234"`,if 'someString' remains constant and rest keeps changing,you can use symbols like id*='someString' to locate it.

[You can refer this discussion for more info.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882463/how-to-click-on-button-submit-quote-its-id-div-5-1-1-lnk-is-dynamically-chan/20884725#20884725)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='contentPane']/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div");
```

Try this code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("contentPane");
```